# Image analysis program in python or ipython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, scipy, jupyter-notebook

English is not my primary language, so I apologize for the possibly hard-to-understand text. I will try my best.

I've been doing image analysis with matlab for a couple of months, and now I've been asked to implement my program on a lab. The thing is, they have to buy the license, and that made me think about free alternatives to matlab. I've always had some sympathy for python since I started programming, so I gave a chance to the SciPy package.

At first sight it looked wonderful, and just what I needed. All the functions that I use, mainly `imshow`, `imread`, some morphological operations like close/open, and basic image analysis are present, but my problem is the following (sorry for the long intro, I wanted to be clear).

I've started replicating my matlab programs in python. For example, reading a series of images of different folders. The thing is, I have made my program functional typing line by line in the ipython notebook, but when it comes to make an actual program which I can run with `# python myprogram.py`, it doesn't work. I understand that ipython and python are not fully compatible. Anyway, when I've tried the IDE Spyder, it works perfectly (almost as matlab) with python, but not with ipython. Taking into account that my program has to be as easy to use as possible (it's for people who hardly know anything about programming or computers), I don't know if:

1. Program in ipython with ipython notebook
2. Program in ipython with plain text, then `#ipython my_program.ipy`
3. Program in python, using or not and IDE, and to run it `#python my_program`

It's important that in the program I will use `imshow` a lot, and I don't know if Spyder or Ipython's notebook has support for it. Thank you very very much for taking your time to read my long question, hopefully someone will answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, I can't find a question to answer. Your question is undefined. In order to increase your chances of getting a useful answer, please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and update accordingly.

Comment: Maybe do PCA on images with scitkit-learn? Difficult to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Python and IPython is fully compatible so long as you don't use IPython magics (lines starting with a percentage sign). I assume that you might be missing a call to the show function? When you create a matplotlib plot (e.g. `plt.imshow`) you must call `plt.show()` to view the plot. This will freeze python and no code (with few exceptions) will be run before all matplotlib windows are closed.